# Firebase Analytics function not being recognized

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I just followed the iOS firebase guide for setting up crashlytics and analytics and whenever I try to use the analytics functions, they aren't being recognized.

The IDE throws this error `Type 'Analytics' has no member 'logEvent'`
whenever I try to use the following function

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventSelectContent, parameters: [
  AnalyticsParameterItemID: "id-\(title!)",
  AnalyticsParameterItemName: title!,
  AnalyticsParameterContentType: "cont"
  ])
```

I've even tried importing all the following at the top of the file and the same thing occurs.

```
import FirebaseAnalytics
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseCrashlytics
import FirebaseInstallations
```

These are the Firebase libraries that get added when I run `pod install`

```
Installing Firebase (6.33.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (6.8.3)
Installing FirebaseCore (6.10.3)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.7.0)
Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (4.6.1)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (1.7.0)
```

And these are the ones I specify in the podfile

```
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? are you sure you have opened the .xcworkspace?

Comment: @Claudio yes - I've also re-installed pods multiple times and even deleted the .xcworkspace and re-made it with pods

Comment: Have you tried only importing `import FirebaseAnalytics` ?

Comment: @Claudio Yes I've also done that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...apparently our project had an enum namespace named 'Analytics' that was overriding the library. This was confirmed when I called the function with `Firebase.Analytics.logEvent()`

:(